# Change active database in doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Using Doctrine, I need to run "SHOW DATABASES" and for each database perform some sanity checks.

What I did is:

```
$config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
$connectionParams = array('url' => $DB_URL, );
$conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);
$conn->prepare("SHOW DATABASES")
....
```

Now that I have the list of DB's, how can issue the Doctrine's equivalent of `USE my_db` ? So that further SQL's are executed on that database?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a database management system you use. In common case you should create a new connection if you want to use a new database.

Database is a part of connection params you give to a `\Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager` to get a connection. (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html)